# Is glibc used in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am wondering if any of you know, whether or not react-native uses glibc library as their dependency. I've searched everywhere, and the only thing I've found was the [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/5c2720b089dd0fb277771b0ac8b0e7788c493e5d/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/third-party/glibc/BUCK). It says:

> NOTE(agallagher): The platform really should be responsible for providing
>   this type of provided dependency.  As it is now, we need to setup dummy
>   rules to model glibc's libraries.

Does anyone know anything else?

Comment: Very few programs do not depend on the libc

Answer (score 3):

React Native does depend on some components of glibc (like pthread which is the first mentioned precompiled library in the link you mentioned) but those same components are offered by [Bionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_(software)), Android's own C library.

Since Bionic is precompiled and bundled with the OS, React Native leverages that implementation instead of using glibc, which explains the note:

> The platform really should be responsible for providing this type of provided dependency.

On iOS, pthread and other C libraries needed by React Native are already available through the iOS SDK.